# Why are software names on the dash different than the actual binary names?

Tags: 22.04

Why, for instance, is `/snap/bin/snap-store` identified in the dash as **Ubuntu Software** with no means to cross-reference? I'm sure that **Ubuntu Software** is more user-friendly, but why isn't the binary then named "Ubuntu Software"? I could accept the binary with a friendly name or the dash icon named **snap-store**. I'd just really like to have a clue what binary is behind some of the system tools. Even the **Help** tool binary isn't named the same as the Help window. Searching (`ps -e | grep -i help`) shows nothing related to the Help display!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names and the corresponding binaries or commands are saved in the `.desktop` files with options `Name` and `Exec`, e.g.:

```
Name=Ubuntu Software
Exec=snap-store
```

---

You can get a list of all names and binaries side by side like this:

```
grep -hPo '^(Name|Exec)=\K.*' /usr/share/applications/*.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop | paste - - | column -t -s$'\t' | sort -u
```

Comment: Perfect! I searched for such a cross-reference and hadn't found it. Until 22.04, it hadn't bothered me too much, but with snaps intruding it suddenly became too much for this poor fossilising brain. (Unix (BSD) since 1982; Solaris since 1984; Linux since 2014; times sure are changing.)

Comment: Possibly the least intuitive one is 'seahorse` for Passwords and Keys...